# Auto complete of string unions inside discriminated objects

Tags: typescript

I am having string unions `value` inside an object discriminated by `discrUnion`:

```
type Discriminated =
  | {
      discrUnion: 'a';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'z';
      value: '8' | '9';
    };
```

I can now create a valid instance:

```
const test: Discriminated = {
  discrUnion: 'a',
  value: '1',
};
```

I can also create invalid instances:

```
const test2: Discriminated = {
  discrUnion: 'a',
  value: '8',
};

// or

const test: Discriminated = {
  discrUnion: 'z',
  value: '1',
};
```

Type checking works well here, and i am pointing out that type checking is **not** my problem.

My problem is that VS Codes auto completion offers me `'1' | '2' | '8' | '9'` for `value`, no matter what i set `discrUnion` to. What i actually expect is auto completion offering me `'1' | '2'` for `discrUnion: 'a'` and offering me `'8' | '9'` for `discrUnion: 'z'`.

Now, after several trial and error, i found out that when having at least 10 different options for `discrUnion`, the auto completion in VS Code actually starts making the job as i expect. Meaning, with 9 or less different options for `discrUnion`, i am still getting invalid values offered by auto completion for `value`, but after adding the 10th option, it works. Here's an example that offers correct auto completion on instantiation:

```
type DiscriminatedWithTenOptions =
  | {
      discrUnion: 'a';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'b';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'c';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'd';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'e';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'f';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'g';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'h';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'i';
      value: '1' | '2';
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: 'z';
      value: '8' | '9';
    };
```

So far, so good. But now, when i have an intersection of this second working example of `DiscriminatedWithTenOptions` with another type, auto completion again offers me invalid values that i don't want. Example:

```
type Intersected = DiscriminatedWithTenOptions & {anotherValue: number};
```

Instantiating `Intersected` leads to auto completion offering me invalid values again.

**My questions:**

1. **Why does auto complete for `value` only work with ten or more options for the discriminating union `discrUnion`?**
2. **Why does auto complete for `value` not work when intersecting `DiscriminatedWithTenOptions` with another type?**

*UPDATE*

I think that it is a typescript problem and not a VS Code problem, because the error message of `tsc` also differs:

Following code leads to following error:

```
type Discriminated =
  | {
      discrUnion: "a";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "z";
      value: "8" | "9";
    };

const disc: Discriminated = {
  discrUnion: "a",
  value: "8",
};
```

[image]

And following code leads to another error:

```
type Discriminated =
  | {
      discrUnion: "a";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "b";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "c";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "d";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "e";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "f";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "g";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "h";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "i";
      value: "1" | "2";
    }
  | {
      discrUnion: "z";
      value: "8" | "9";
    };

const disc: Discriminated = {
  discrUnion: "a",
  value: "8",
};
```

[image]

Comment: To be clear, this is just an issue you have with VS code and not a Typescript issue?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think it's a typescript issue, see my updated post above.